# Excel I have a .Net object compiled as a tlb but cant not access any methods apart from Dispose

Tags: c#, interface, excel, vba

This is ongoing issue to something I posted yesterday.

I have a .net object that I want to use in Excel. I have an existing VBA script that i need to alter to call this the object from. I have then converted the object to a TLB. I've not really touched on this area before so any help will be appreciated.

I have created an interface

```
[Guid("0F700B48-E0CA-446b-B87E-555BCC317D74"),InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IOfficeCOMInterface
{

    [DispId(1)]
    void ResetOrder();
    [DispId(2)]
    void SetDeliveryAddress(string PostalName, string AddressLine1, string AddressLine2, string AddressLine3, string AddressLine4, string PostCode, string CountryCode, string TelephoneNo, string FaxNo, string EmailAddress);
}
```

I have also created an class that inherits that object.

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ProgId("NAMESPACE.OfficeCOMInterface"), Guid("9D9723F9-8CF1-4834-BE69-C3FEAAAAB530"), ComVisible(true)]
public class OfficeCOMInterface : IOfficeCOMInterface, IDisposable
{
 public void ResetSOPOrder()
    {

    }
public void SetDeliveryAddress(string PostalName, string AddressLine1, string AddressLine2, string AddressLine3, string AddressLine4, string PostCode, string CountryCode, string TelephoneNo, string FaxNo, string EmailAddress)
    {

        try
        {
            SalesOrder.AmendDeliveryAddress(PostalName, AddressLine1, AddressLine2, AddressLine3, AddressLine4, PostCode);

            MessageBox.Show("Delivery address set");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't access the object methods apart from dispose, I guess IDisposable is working fine. Is there anything I need to my Interface?

Comment: Is your .NET assembly actually registered using regasm?

Comment: NB: I know this is a just sample, but it seems to show a misunderstanding which happens easily. The code `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` is not doing anything useful actually. `throw ex;` will reset the stack trace and you will loose important information. This is probably not what you expect it to do and it is almost never what you want. You probably simply want to re-throw the exception (e.g. after writing to the log). To do so replace `throw ex;` with a simple `throw;`.

Comment: Hi yes I used regasm.

I have more code on that exception but I thought id simplify it for the example.

Everytime I try and create an instance I receive an error The System cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Does the error message give any more details which file cannot be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let anyone know I used the instructions here and managed to get it working.

http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/

thanks for replying 0xA3